# Salesforce(apex) Query return values with toLowerCase

Tags: salesforce, apex

I using Salesforce (apex), i need Query that will select values from table and return them in toLowerCase.

some think like this:

//only example (not working code)

```
 for(Users user:[select Name.toLowerCase(),LastName.toLowerCase() from Users ] )
 {  
  //code....
 }
```

For example if i have table Users with

**Name | LastName**

```
Boby | Testovich1

Dany | Testovich2

Ron  | Testovich3
```

Query need to return me all values with toLowerCase:

> **b**oby **t**estovich1,**d**any **t**estovich2,**r**on **t**estovich3

I can do this like this

```
  for(Users user:[select Name,LastName from Users ] )
     {  
     string UserName=user.Name.toLowerCase();
     }
```

but is there a way to to this with querying?

Is there a way to do this in Salesforce (apex) Query ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Salesforce(apex) Query select with Where toLowerCase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39557852/salesforceapex-query-select-with-where-tolowercase)

Comment: This questions are both my.Here i need to return all  values with LowerCase,and in the second i need to make where statement by LowerCase that mean if i looking for 'boby' in table and there is 'BOBY' in the table i still will find it.i don't understand why you decide that this is the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't transform the return value to lower case in the query, you'll need to do it after you've gotten the query results.

One alternative is to add a formula field that returns the lower case value and query that instead.

Comment: Very sad to hear it, was hoping there is a way to do this in query. 
Thanks for explanation.