# Salesforce(apex) Query select with Where toLowerCase

Tags: salesforce, apex

I using Salesforce (apex), I need to Query with a WHERE statement with toLowerCase ,i.e. I have a list (MyNames_list) with LowerCase values but the table values are not lowerCase.

In my Query  when I check the Name in MyNames_list it will make toLowerCase value and then check it in the MyNames_list.

Something like this:

```
Name | LastName

BOBY | Testovich1

DANY | Testovich2

Ron  | Testovich3
```

and in my list:

> MyNames_list :boby,dany,ron

That still will return me all rows, because WHERE statement will check it with  LowerCase.

//only example (not working code)

```
for(Users user:[SELECT Name,LastName FROM Users 
                WHERE ( Name.toLowerCase() IN : MyNames_list) ] )
{  
    //code....
}
```

Is there a way to do this in Salesforce (apex) Query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce is only case-sensitive for fields that are explicitly case-sensitive (ie an external id that has been marked as case-sensitive)

The field you are querying, `Name` is not case-sensitive - hence, you don't need to apply `toLowerCase()`. You will get all matching fields anyway.

So your query could be:

```
for(User u:[SELECT Name,LastName FROM User WHERE Name IN :MyNames_list)]){  
//code....
}
```

Comment: You mean if i will look for 'boby' ,and in the table it is 'Boby' the WHERE statement will still find it with regular  querying->(WHERE Name IN ....)?

Comment: Thanks for explanation.

Comment: maybe you know answer to this question as well?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39557672/salesforceapex-query-return-values-with-tolowercase